# Cassandra is not starting up

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to install Cassandra in Windows 10 machine. 
Cassandra is not starting after the below log

```
Initializing system_auth.roles
```

Environment Set up is 
Windows 10
Java 8
Python 2.7
Cassandra 3.0.18

More logs

```
INFO  19:51:00 Initializing system.IndexInfo
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.batches
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.paxos
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.local
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.peers
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.peer_events
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.range_xfers
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.compaction_history
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.sstable_activity
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.size_estimates
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.available_ranges
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.views_builds_in_progress
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.built_views
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.hints
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.batchlog
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.schema_keyspaces
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.schema_columnfamilies
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.schema_columns
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.schema_triggers
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.schema_usertypes
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.schema_functions
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system.schema_aggregates
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system_schema.keyspaces
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system_schema.tables
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system_schema.columns
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system_schema.triggers
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system_schema.dropped_columns
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system_schema.views
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system_schema.types
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system_schema.functions
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system_schema.aggregates
INFO  19:51:01 Initializing system_schema.indexes
INFO  19:51:03 Initializing key cache with capacity of 100 MBs.
INFO  19:51:03 Initializing row cache with capacity of 0 MBs
INFO  19:51:03 Initializing counter cache with capacity of 50 MBs
INFO  19:51:03 Scheduling counter cache save to every 7200 seconds (going to save all keys).
INFO  19:51:04 Global buffer pool is enabled, when pool is exahusted (max is 512 mb) it will allocate on heap
INFO  19:51:05 Populating token metadata from system tables
INFO  19:51:05 Token metadata:
INFO  19:51:05 Completed loading (1 ms; 4 keys) KeyCache cache
INFO  19:51:05 No commitlog files found; skipping replay
INFO  19:51:05 Populating token metadata from system tables
INFO  19:51:05 Token metadata:
INFO  19:51:05 Cassandra version: 3.0.18
INFO  19:51:05 Thrift API version: 20.1.0
INFO  19:51:05 CQL supported versions: 3.4.0 (default: 3.4.0)
INFO  19:51:05 Initializing index summary manager with a memory pool size of 149 MB and a resize interval of 60 minutes
INFO  19:51:05 Loading persisted ring state
WARN  19:51:05 No host ID found, created 0b40a32e-02fa-4e30-9ba9-0e5ad98c0dd1 (Note: This should happen exactly once per node).
INFO  19:51:05 Starting up server gossip
INFO  19:51:05 Starting Messaging Service on localhost/127.0.0.1:7000 (Software Loopback Interface 1)
INFO  19:51:05 This node will not auto bootstrap because it is configured to be a seed node.
INFO  19:51:05 Generated random tokens. tokens are [-4134944950494758894, 8107901106817729607, 3821468126845792016, -5964936849830565247, -4033202653259934007, 6465574400681688423, -8339193796864520803, -9102087309145389149, 4559631769127444692, -4923191519882908425, 6319195729140676410, 5573228672448334845, -377057351788121552, 3992422319852338092, -4475583651565054349, 7535620683717279894, -2481141779520805514, 8014193788349246559, 2771154564041888602, 4735036525052432758, 4704450512259603736, 9137256080136088408, -5664378188784768179, -7355835526907762891, -8739480561619334892, 6593314337245504478, 2782236440012166634, 7517907875075727134, 1005966352682564970, -6329620374968789191, -4790939518954941409, -8155297896503024033, -8437046006383589784, 4341687362092853380, -2925444581629165796, 3157881734729908252, -5457578781401857065, 1852693779433242222, 2087296166851930177, 6221636226980376547, -4627122309406467381, -2078294789719140673, 2126151187144530538, -2416242928113055943, -2467516010282581161, 2697833181014472825, 6092481156198013565, 8170571180582534317, 1234450279220588377, 5820859378637220223, -260223943062090191, -6769160492715812314, 4530423611042649339, -5811506907653363220, -7166831021099153951, -3392688456660535696, -2374073182252696726, 104618561781417698, 6076393259519474789, 7029431140125626329, -2461124666370511230, 3413063964889961537, -5566237785741724414, 9175001681479269487, -7522073093607560324, 112985976928537695, -9181862820768946749, -3604288764664657608, 3631581900773472988, 1246095632924785692, 7471681123214330216, -2747351753537505231, -513619147301991573, 6063409661908440051, 7294259971635646430, -8294861676242698827, 5922633991422121423, -5786049256956268095, -1778692611501801118, -4990395376039480404, -804468927196650453, 6449482013672981153, -236527058208575409, 8023892623428676468, -5762226519602032916, 7880937308991458523, -1639148538461981640, -1605420879219543006, 6030791994810955937, 8858138698098199845, -8020885962018010290, 8610424201901637936, 2598537157451720932, -1702392791685505218, -5528388534825489140, 4851861781481410426, 4830730487170059117, 7404694329729734564, 2117065546342488501, 3183081147587380391, -650549560327919755, 1181253165251712879, 1028512276643589790, 2246450662945421633, 7249448214758104771, -1711239192062849856, 1168263067395645865, -184639302718296128, 3452984580375732264, 6703626617590080323, 3185266376119526312, -2191767971922662232, 6777730416371068450, 3662440595706866291, 5132811699894794208, -4029759277330301988, -8220329429368507605, -6543954434316937237, 547223580421356605, -635495249143248914, -5619292849599664478, 8107980558679933135, -4306495677151091566, -4873490200112391890, -3174177833065131744, -2940342107416310004, 7492431597309764513, -4637064187860279306, 599068803292954360, -2571872730491117125, -4241954329398283796, 1130557170092703452, -6420442989470774528, -8639533785857232862, -4633627197625295404, -479326565022557918, -6435457963566934505, 2028158485541761723, -5936377158770489764, 4140027543360385326, -8050930180962295628, -2856254685018191550, 9000073003030305138, -2292094204464824715, -7073613288559896547, -7437854498982048646, -8299770080468079954, 7574264438904804501, -5102033221229166687, -1773195173866189717, 3034328872066363908, 4304803727150805030, -3064259832417862527, -2570709842167228573, -7028156071583981771, 3310718302579204254, -3960035626520745990, -8162167815746521252, -7071910878390305735, 6983613546338207307, 8863818969831369846, -6813247722439587774, -1816003130966857995, -5255093183924125086, -749931575051585320, -6080195045458058654, -3530080003515882215, 4552508915946832653, -5855569995116522415, 1153087246811817643, 214442424887691688, -4182166871179717081, -6289628614426246642, -7944863901679748340, -5469373278692587264, 1850326271673703056, 3510307113911564114, -8465579815208859871, -3862279700330296701, -398507677121272679, -4146981629242332729, 4566818784861568567, -8456634614417512433, -7539216054530012142, -4667561878436757510, 176127536243263200, 3399512434509026495, 6716716167099001985, -9135152589821893130, -7532258728384325940, -7107005448763231839, -4040702351792514978, 4668181545894058968, 5298746237590038487, 7288898888645823805, -4496678018012661193, -2949382491499904091, -4555368585890967089, 4459343349150993139, 8134751885909642591, -7346055236722684792, 1398972207818014866, 7485724455509988847, -8410353044617211568, 6012776112756389920, 1576639549642827365, -1509619856549957021, -6971092109202137033, 6955703574182215845, 8142146290049995776, -5914575457693555113, -1850755541907922396, 6301336643499188089, -3902685839909140519, -4352992374285928202, 4399615400033738524, -8932233076910266584, 5973108789268530823, 1235528578328242488, 563024221547287208, -4354471365375775908, -8438976104446486307, -3348358867190453249, -4888854025867962921, -2685938229628362703, -3198318217854425467, 8380824499931187134, -3055357048702271817, 6395301512694036082, 1531163091609683667, -7607253375299117036, -468314594624929191, -6976950500978614980, 7072046800929505960, 3788129317550054144, 984567617652880615, 8982782230679876578, 1503387362356614856, 4222206253102852569, 280848228597580944, -3925670621121727018, -3076436432342030870, -1755196762452758851, -4766844696738008200, 1064950196043905855, 2118853807757928087, -246779164796970348, -6417557700271539217, -2910324000567532759, 4205725228545201454, 6737061596991258059, 2229954979637633879, -7076806135574931287, 8563416734421856731, 3023089769404515667, 8287028455320079982]
INFO  19:51:05 Create new Keyspace: KeyspaceMetadata{name=system_traces, params=KeyspaceParams{durable_writes=true, replication=ReplicationParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy, replication_factor=2}}, tables=[org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@68084f64[cfId=c5e99f16-8677-3914-b17e-960613512345,ksName=system_traces,cfName=sessions,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=tracing sessions, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=0, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@4f8a0b6d, extensions={}},comparator=comparator(),partitionColumns=[[] | [client command coordinator duration request started_at parameters]],partitionKeyColumns=[ColumnDefinition{name=session_id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}],clusteringColumns=[],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType,columnMetadata=[ColumnDefinition{name=client, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.InetAddressType, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=command, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=session_id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}, ColumnDefinition{name=coordinator, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.InetAddressType, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=request, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=started_at, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=duration, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=parameters, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MapType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type), kind=REGULAR, position=-1}],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]], org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@a9f0e04[cfId=8826e8e9-e16a-3728-8753-3bc1fc713c25,ksName=system_traces,cfName=events,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=tracing events, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=0, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@4f8a0b6d, extensions={}},comparator=comparator(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType),partitionColumns=[[] | [activity source source_elapsed thread]],partitionKeyColumns=[ColumnDefinition{name=session_id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}],clusteringColumns=[ColumnDefinition{name=event_id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType, kind=CLUSTERING, position=0}],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType,columnMetadata=[ColumnDefinition{name=activity, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=event_id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType, kind=CLUSTERING, position=0}, ColumnDefinition{name=session_id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}, ColumnDefinition{name=source, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.InetAddressType, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=thread, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=source_elapsed, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]]], views=[], functions=[], types=[]}
INFO  19:51:09 Initializing system_traces.events
INFO  19:51:09 Initializing system_traces.sessions
INFO  19:51:09 Create new Keyspace: KeyspaceMetadata{name=system_distributed, params=KeyspaceParams{durable_writes=true, replication=ReplicationParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy, replication_factor=3}}, tables=[org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@16e40499[cfId=759fffad-624b-3181-80ee-fa9a52d1f627,ksName=system_distributed,cfName=repair_history,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=Repair history, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=0, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@4f8a0b6d, extensions={}},comparator=comparator(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType),partitionColumns=[[] | [coordinator exception_message exception_stacktrace finished_at parent_id range_begin range_end started_at status participants]],partitionKeyColumns=[ColumnDefinition{name=keyspace_name, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}, ColumnDefinition{name=columnfamily_name, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=1}],clusteringColumns=[ColumnDefinition{name=id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType, kind=CLUSTERING, position=0}],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type),columnMetadata=[ColumnDefinition{name=status, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType, kind=CLUSTERING, position=0}, ColumnDefinition{name=coordinator, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.InetAddressType, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=finished_at, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=participants, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.SetType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.InetAddressType), kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=exception_stacktrace, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=parent_id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=range_end, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=range_begin, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=exception_message, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=keyspace_name, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}, ColumnDefinition{name=started_at, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=columnfamily_name, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=1}],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]], org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@6c7ece9b[cfId=deabd734-b99d-3b9c-92e5-fd92eb5abf14,ksName=system_distributed,cfName=parent_repair_history,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=Repair history, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=0, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@4f8a0b6d, extensions={}},comparator=comparator(),partitionColumns=[[] | [exception_message exception_stacktrace finished_at keyspace_name started_at columnfamily_names requested_ranges successful_ranges]],partitionKeyColumns=[ColumnDefinition{name=parent_id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}],clusteringColumns=[],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType,columnMetadata=[ColumnDefinition{name=requested_ranges, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.SetType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type), kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=exception_message, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=keyspace_name, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=successful_ranges, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.SetType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type), kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=started_at, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=finished_at, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=exception_stacktrace, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=parent_id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}, ColumnDefinition{name=columnfamily_names, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.SetType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type), kind=REGULAR, position=-1}],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]]], views=[], functions=[], types=[]}
INFO  19:51:11 Initializing system_distributed.parent_repair_history
INFO  19:51:11 Initializing system_distributed.repair_history
INFO  19:51:12 Create new Keyspace: KeyspaceMetadata{name=system_auth, params=KeyspaceParams{durable_writes=true, replication=ReplicationParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy, replication_factor=1}}, tables=[org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@4b970cb0[cfId=5bc52802-de25-35ed-aeab-188eecebb090,ksName=system_auth,cfName=roles,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=role definitions, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=7776000, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@4f8a0b6d, extensions={}},comparator=comparator(),partitionColumns=[[] | [can_login is_superuser salted_hash member_of]],partitionKeyColumns=[ColumnDefinition{name=role, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}],clusteringColumns=[],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,columnMetadata=[ColumnDefinition{name=salted_hash, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=member_of, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.SetType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type), kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=role, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}, ColumnDefinition{name=can_login, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}, ColumnDefinition{name=is_superuser, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType, kind=REGULAR, position=-1}],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]], org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@78792074[cfId=0ecdaa87-f8fb-3e60-88d1-74fb36fe5c0d,ksName=system_auth,cfName=role_members,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=role memberships lookup table, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=7776000, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@4f8a0b6d, extensions={}},comparator=comparator(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type),partitionColumns=[[] | []],partitionKeyColumns=[ColumnDefinition{name=role, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}],clusteringColumns=[ColumnDefinition{name=member, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=CLUSTERING, position=0}],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,columnMetadata=[ColumnDefinition{name=role, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}, ColumnDefinition{name=member, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=CLUSTERING, position=0}],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]], org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@46085234[cfId=3afbe79f-2194-31a7-add7-f5ab90d8ec9c,ksName=system_auth,cfName=role_permissions,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=permissions granted to db roles, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=7776000, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@4f8a0b6d, extensions={}},comparator=comparator(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type),partitionColumns=[[] | [permissions]],partitionKeyColumns=[ColumnDefinition{name=role, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}],clusteringColumns=[ColumnDefinition{name=resource, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=CLUSTERING, position=0}],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,columnMetadata=[ColumnDefinition{name=role, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}, ColumnDefinition{name=resource, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=CLUSTERING, position=0}, ColumnDefinition{name=permissions, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.SetType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type), kind=REGULAR, position=-1}],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]], org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@369faf01[cfId=5f2fbdad-91f1-3946-bd25-d5da3a5c35ec,ksName=system_auth,cfName=resource_role_permissons_index,flags=[COMPOUND],params=TableParams{comment=index of db roles with permissions granted on a resource, read_repair_chance=0.0, dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.0, bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01, crc_check_chance=1.0, gc_grace_seconds=7776000, default_time_to_live=0, memtable_flush_period_in_ms=3600000, min_index_interval=128, max_index_interval=2048, speculative_retry=99PERCENTILE, caching={'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'}, compaction=CompactionParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, options={min_threshold=4, max_threshold=32}}, compression=org.apache.cassandra.schema.CompressionParams@4f8a0b6d, extensions={}},comparator=comparator(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type),partitionColumns=[[] | []],partitionKeyColumns=[ColumnDefinition{name=resource, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}],clusteringColumns=[ColumnDefinition{name=role, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=CLUSTERING, position=0}],keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,columnMetadata=[ColumnDefinition{name=resource, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=PARTITION_KEY, position=0}, ColumnDefinition{name=role, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=CLUSTERING, position=0}],droppedColumns={},triggers=[],indexes=[]]], views=[], functions=[], types=[]}
INFO  19:51:12 Initializing system_auth.resource_role_permissons_index
INFO  19:51:12 Initializing system_auth.role_members
INFO  19:51:12 Initializing system_auth.role_permissions
INFO  19:51:12 Initializing system_auth.roles
```

Comment: What was the error in system.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Killed the process in command line and started again. 
Now Cassandra started normally.

```
WARN  20:14:11 JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
INFO  20:14:11 Initializing SIGAR library
WARN  20:14:11 Cassandra server running in degraded mode. Is swap disabled? : false,  Address space adequate? : true,  nofile limit adequate? : true, nproc limit adequate? : true
INFO  20:14:14 Initializing system.IndexInfo
INFO  20:14:15 Initializing system.batches
INFO  20:14:15 Initializing system.paxos
INFO  20:14:15 Initializing system.local
INFO  20:14:15 Global buffer pool is enabled, when pool is exahusted (max is 512 mb) it will allocate on heap
INFO  20:14:15 Initializing key cache with capacity of 100 MBs.
INFO  20:14:15 Initializing row cache with capacity of 0 MBs
INFO  20:14:15 Initializing counter cache with capacity of 50 MBs
INFO  20:14:15 Scheduling counter cache save to every 7200 seconds (going to save all keys).
INFO  20:14:15 Initializing system.peers
INFO  20:14:15 Initializing system.peer_events
INFO  20:14:15 Initializing system.range_xfers
INFO  20:14:15 Initializing system.compaction_history
INFO  20:14:15 Initializing system.sstable_activity
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system.size_estimates
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system.available_ranges
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system.views_builds_in_progress
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system.built_views
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system.hints
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system.batchlog
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system.schema_keyspaces
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system.schema_columnfamilies
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system.schema_columns
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system.schema_triggers
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system.schema_usertypes
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system.schema_functions
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system.schema_aggregates
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system_schema.keyspaces
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system_schema.tables
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system_schema.columns
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system_schema.triggers
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system_schema.dropped_columns
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system_schema.views
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system_schema.types
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system_schema.functions
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system_schema.aggregates
INFO  20:14:16 Initializing system_schema.indexes
INFO  20:14:19 Populating token metadata from system tables
INFO  20:14:19 Token metadata: Normal Tokens:
localhost/127.0.0.1:[-9181862820768946749, -9135152589821893130, -9102087309145389149, -8932233076910266584, -8739480561619334892, -8639533785857232862, -8465579815208859871, -8456634614417512433, -8438976104446486307, -8437046006383589784, -8410353044617211568, -8339193796864520803, -8299770080468079954, -8294861676242698827, -8220329429368507605, -8162167815746521252, -8155297896503024033, -8050930180962295628, -8020885962018010290, -7944863901679748340, -7607253375299117036, -7539216054530012142, -7532258728384325940, -7522073093607560324, -7437854498982048646, -7355835526907762891, -7346055236722684792, -7166831021099153951, -7107005448763231839, -7076806135574931287, -7073613288559896547, -7071910878390305735, -7028156071583981771, -6976950500978614980, -6971092109202137033, -6813247722439587774, -6769160492715812314, -6543954434316937237, -6435457963566934505, -6420442989470774528, -6417557700271539217, -6329620374968789191, -6289628614426246642, -6080195045458058654, -5964936849830565247, -5936377158770489764, -5914575457693555113, -5855569995116522415, -5811506907653363220, -5786049256956268095, -5762226519602032916, -5664378188784768179, -5619292849599664478, -5566237785741724414, -5528388534825489140, -5469373278692587264, -5457578781401857065, -5255093183924125086, -5102033221229166687, -4990395376039480404, -4923191519882908425, -4888854025867962921, -4873490200112391890, -4790939518954941409, -4766844696738008200, -4667561878436757510, -4637064187860279306, -4633627197625295404, -4627122309406467381, -4555368585890967089, -4496678018012661193, -4475583651565054349, -4354471365375775908, -4352992374285928202, -4306495677151091566, -4241954329398283796, -4182166871179717081, -4146981629242332729, -4134944950494758894, -4040702351792514978, -4033202653259934007, -4029759277330301988, -3960035626520745990, -3925670621121727018, -3902685839909140519, -3862279700330296701, -3604288764664657608, -3530080003515882215, -3392688456660535696, -3348358867190453249, -3198318217854425467, -3174177833065131744, -3076436432342030870, -3064259832417862527, -3055357048702271817, -2949382491499904091, -2940342107416310004, -2925444581629165796, -2910324000567532759, -2856254685018191550, -2747351753537505231, -2685938229628362703, -2571872730491117125, -2570709842167228573, -2481141779520805514, -2467516010282581161, -2461124666370511230, -2416242928113055943, -2374073182252696726, -2292094204464824715, -2191767971922662232, -2078294789719140673, -1850755541907922396, -1816003130966857995, -1778692611501801118, -1773195173866189717, -1755196762452758851, -1711239192062849856, -1702392791685505218, -1639148538461981640, -1605420879219543006, -1509619856549957021, -804468927196650453, -749931575051585320, -650549560327919755, -635495249143248914, -513619147301991573, -479326565022557918, -468314594624929191, -398507677121272679, -377057351788121552, -260223943062090191, -246779164796970348, -236527058208575409, -184639302718296128, 104618561781417698, 112985976928537695, 176127536243263200, 214442424887691688, 280848228597580944, 547223580421356605, 563024221547287208, 599068803292954360, 984567617652880615, 1005966352682564970, 1028512276643589790, 1064950196043905855, 1130557170092703452, 1153087246811817643, 1168263067395645865, 1181253165251712879, 1234450279220588377, 1235528578328242488, 1246095632924785692, 1398972207818014866, 1503387362356614856, 1531163091609683667, 1576639549642827365, 1850326271673703056, 1852693779433242222, 2028158485541761723, 2087296166851930177, 2117065546342488501, 2118853807757928087, 2126151187144530538, 2229954979637633879, 2246450662945421633, 2598537157451720932, 2697833181014472825, 2771154564041888602, 2782236440012166634, 3023089769404515667, 3034328872066363908, 3157881734729908252, 3183081147587380391, 3185266376119526312, 3310718302579204254, 3399512434509026495, 3413063964889961537, 3452984580375732264, 3510307113911564114, 3631581900773472988, 3662440595706866291, 3788129317550054144, 3821468126845792016, 3992422319852338092, 4140027543360385326, 4205725228545201454, 4222206253102852569, 4304803727150805030, 4341687362092853380, 4399615400033738524, 4459343349150993139, 4530423611042649339, 4552508915946832653, 4559631769127444692, 4566818784861568567, 4668181545894058968, 4704450512259603736, 4735036525052432758, 4830730487170059117, 4851861781481410426, 5132811699894794208, 5298746237590038487, 5573228672448334845, 5820859378637220223, 5922633991422121423, 5973108789268530823, 6012776112756389920, 6030791994810955937, 6063409661908440051, 6076393259519474789, 6092481156198013565, 6221636226980376547, 6301336643499188089, 6319195729140676410, 6395301512694036082, 6449482013672981153, 6465574400681688423, 6593314337245504478, 6703626617590080323, 6716716167099001985, 6737061596991258059, 6777730416371068450, 6955703574182215845, 6983613546338207307, 7029431140125626329, 7072046800929505960, 7249448214758104771, 7288898888645823805, 7294259971635646430, 7404694329729734564, 7471681123214330216, 7485724455509988847, 7492431597309764513, 7517907875075727134, 7535620683717279894, 7574264438904804501, 7880937308991458523, 8014193788349246559, 8023892623428676468, 8107901106817729607, 8107980558679933135, 8134751885909642591, 8142146290049995776, 8170571180582534317, 8287028455320079982, 8380824499931187134, 8563416734421856731, 8610424201901637936, 8858138698098199845, 8863818969831369846, 8982782230679876578, 9000073003030305138, 9137256080136088408, 9175001681479269487]

INFO  20:14:20 Initializing system_distributed.parent_repair_history
INFO  20:14:20 Initializing system_distributed.repair_history
INFO  20:14:20 Initializing system_auth.resource_role_permissons_index
INFO  20:14:20 Initializing system_auth.role_members
INFO  20:14:20 Initializing system_auth.role_permissions
INFO  20:14:20 Initializing system_auth.roles
INFO  20:14:20 Initializing system_traces.events
INFO  20:14:20 Initializing system_traces.sessions
INFO  20:14:20 Completed loading (2 ms; 14 keys) KeyCache cache
INFO  20:14:20 Replaying E:\app\apache-cassandra-3.0.18\data\commitlog\CommitLog-6-1568317861452.log
INFO  20:14:20 Log replay complete, 0 replayed mutations
INFO  20:14:20 Populating token metadata from system tables
INFO  20:14:20 Token metadata: Normal Tokens:
localhost/127.0.0.1:[-9181862820768946749, -9135152589821893130, -9102087309145389149, -8932233076910266584, -8739480561619334892, -8639533785857232862, -8465579815208859871, -8456634614417512433, -8438976104446486307, -8437046006383589784, -8410353044617211568, -8339193796864520803, -8299770080468079954, -8294861676242698827, -8220329429368507605, -8162167815746521252, -8155297896503024033, -8050930180962295628, -8020885962018010290, -7944863901679748340, -7607253375299117036, -7539216054530012142, -7532258728384325940, -7522073093607560324, -7437854498982048646, -7355835526907762891, -7346055236722684792, -7166831021099153951, -7107005448763231839, -7076806135574931287, -7073613288559896547, -7071910878390305735, -7028156071583981771, -6976950500978614980, -6971092109202137033, -6813247722439587774, -6769160492715812314, -6543954434316937237, -6435457963566934505, -6420442989470774528, -6417557700271539217, -6329620374968789191, -6289628614426246642, -6080195045458058654, -5964936849830565247, -5936377158770489764, -5914575457693555113, -5855569995116522415, -5811506907653363220, -5786049256956268095, -5762226519602032916, -5664378188784768179, -5619292849599664478, -5566237785741724414, -5528388534825489140, -5469373278692587264, -5457578781401857065, -5255093183924125086, -5102033221229166687, -4990395376039480404, -4923191519882908425, -4888854025867962921, -4873490200112391890, -4790939518954941409, -4766844696738008200, -4667561878436757510, -4637064187860279306, -4633627197625295404, -4627122309406467381, -4555368585890967089, -4496678018012661193, -4475583651565054349, -4354471365375775908, -4352992374285928202, -4306495677151091566, -4241954329398283796, -4182166871179717081, -4146981629242332729, -4134944950494758894, -4040702351792514978, -4033202653259934007, -4029759277330301988, -3960035626520745990, -3925670621121727018, -3902685839909140519, -3862279700330296701, -3604288764664657608, -3530080003515882215, -3392688456660535696, -3348358867190453249, -3198318217854425467, -3174177833065131744, -3076436432342030870, -3064259832417862527, -3055357048702271817, -2949382491499904091, -2940342107416310004, -2925444581629165796, -2910324000567532759, -2856254685018191550, -2747351753537505231, -2685938229628362703, -2571872730491117125, -2570709842167228573, -2481141779520805514, -2467516010282581161, -2461124666370511230, -2416242928113055943, -2374073182252696726, -2292094204464824715, -2191767971922662232, -2078294789719140673, -1850755541907922396, -1816003130966857995, -1778692611501801118, -1773195173866189717, -1755196762452758851, -1711239192062849856, -1702392791685505218, -1639148538461981640, -1605420879219543006, -1509619856549957021, -804468927196650453, -749931575051585320, -650549560327919755, -635495249143248914, -513619147301991573, -479326565022557918, -468314594624929191, -398507677121272679, -377057351788121552, -260223943062090191, -246779164796970348, -236527058208575409, -184639302718296128, 104618561781417698, 112985976928537695, 176127536243263200, 214442424887691688, 280848228597580944, 547223580421356605, 563024221547287208, 599068803292954360, 984567617652880615, 1005966352682564970, 1028512276643589790, 1064950196043905855, 1130557170092703452, 1153087246811817643, 1168263067395645865, 1181253165251712879, 1234450279220588377, 1235528578328242488, 1246095632924785692, 1398972207818014866, 1503387362356614856, 1531163091609683667, 1576639549642827365, 1850326271673703056, 1852693779433242222, 2028158485541761723, 2087296166851930177, 2117065546342488501, 2118853807757928087, 2126151187144530538, 2229954979637633879, 2246450662945421633, 2598537157451720932, 2697833181014472825, 2771154564041888602, 2782236440012166634, 3023089769404515667, 3034328872066363908, 3157881734729908252, 3183081147587380391, 3185266376119526312, 3310718302579204254, 3399512434509026495, 3413063964889961537, 3452984580375732264, 3510307113911564114, 3631581900773472988, 3662440595706866291, 3788129317550054144, 3821468126845792016, 3992422319852338092, 4140027543360385326, 4205725228545201454, 4222206253102852569, 4304803727150805030, 4341687362092853380, 4399615400033738524, 4459343349150993139, 4530423611042649339, 4552508915946832653, 4559631769127444692, 4566818784861568567, 4668181545894058968, 4704450512259603736, 4735036525052432758, 4830730487170059117, 4851861781481410426, 5132811699894794208, 5298746237590038487, 5573228672448334845, 5820859378637220223, 5922633991422121423, 5973108789268530823, 6012776112756389920, 6030791994810955937, 6063409661908440051, 6076393259519474789, 6092481156198013565, 6221636226980376547, 6301336643499188089, 6319195729140676410, 6395301512694036082, 6449482013672981153, 6465574400681688423, 6593314337245504478, 6703626617590080323, 6716716167099001985, 6737061596991258059, 6777730416371068450, 6955703574182215845, 6983613546338207307, 7029431140125626329, 7072046800929505960, 7249448214758104771, 7288898888645823805, 7294259971635646430, 7404694329729734564, 7471681123214330216, 7485724455509988847, 7492431597309764513, 7517907875075727134, 7535620683717279894, 7574264438904804501, 7880937308991458523, 8014193788349246559, 8023892623428676468, 8107901106817729607, 8107980558679933135, 8134751885909642591, 8142146290049995776, 8170571180582534317, 8287028455320079982, 8380824499931187134, 8563416734421856731, 8610424201901637936, 8858138698098199845, 8863818969831369846, 8982782230679876578, 9000073003030305138, 9137256080136088408, 9175001681479269487]

INFO  20:14:20 Cassandra version: 3.0.18
INFO  20:14:20 Thrift API version: 20.1.0
INFO  20:14:20 CQL supported versions: 3.4.0 (default: 3.4.0)
INFO  20:14:20 Initializing index summary manager with a memory pool size of 149 MB and a resize interval of 60 minutes
INFO  20:14:20 Loading persisted ring state
INFO  20:14:20 Starting up server gossip
INFO  20:14:21 Updating topology for localhost/127.0.0.1
INFO  20:14:21 Updating topology for localhost/127.0.0.1
INFO  20:14:22 Starting Messaging Service on localhost/127.0.0.1:7000 (Software Loopback Interface 1)
INFO  20:14:22 Using saved tokens [-1509619856549957021, -1605420879219543006, -1639148538461981640, -1702392791685505218, -1711239192062849856, -1755196762452758851, -1773195173866189717, -1778692611501801118, -1816003130966857995, -184639302718296128, -1850755541907922396, -2078294789719140673, -2191767971922662232, -2292094204464824715, -236527058208575409, -2374073182252696726, -2416242928113055943, -2461124666370511230, -2467516010282581161, -246779164796970348, -2481141779520805514, -2570709842167228573, -2571872730491117125, -260223943062090191, -2685938229628362703, -2747351753537505231, -2856254685018191550, -2910324000567532759, -2925444581629165796, -2940342107416310004, -2949382491499904091, -3055357048702271817, -3064259832417862527, -3076436432342030870, -3174177833065131744, -3198318217854425467, -3348358867190453249, -3392688456660535696, -3530080003515882215, -3604288764664657608, -377057351788121552, -3862279700330296701, -3902685839909140519, -3925670621121727018, -3960035626520745990, -398507677121272679, -4029759277330301988, -4033202653259934007, -4040702351792514978, -4134944950494758894, -4146981629242332729, -4182166871179717081, -4241954329398283796, -4306495677151091566, -4352992374285928202, -4354471365375775908, -4475583651565054349, -4496678018012661193, -4555368585890967089, -4627122309406467381, -4633627197625295404, -4637064187860279306, -4667561878436757510, -468314594624929191, -4766844696738008200, -4790939518954941409, -479326565022557918, -4873490200112391890, -4888854025867962921, -4923191519882908425, -4990395376039480404, -5102033221229166687, -513619147301991573, -5255093183924125086, -5457578781401857065, -5469373278692587264, -5528388534825489140, -5566237785741724414, -5619292849599664478, -5664378188784768179, -5762226519602032916, -5786049256956268095, -5811506907653363220, -5855569995116522415, -5914575457693555113, -5936377158770489764, -5964936849830565247, -6080195045458058654, -6289628614426246642, -6329620374968789191, -635495249143248914, -6417557700271539217, -6420442989470774528, -6435457963566934505, -650549560327919755, -6543954434316937237, -6769160492715812314, -6813247722439587774, -6971092109202137033, -6976950500978614980, -7028156071583981771, -7071910878390305735, -7073613288559896547, -7076806135574931287, -7107005448763231839, -7166831021099153951, -7346055236722684792, -7355835526907762891, -7437854498982048646, -749931575051585320, -7522073093607560324, -7532258728384325940, -7539216054530012142, -7607253375299117036, -7944863901679748340, -8020885962018010290, -804468927196650453, -8050930180962295628, -8155297896503024033, -8162167815746521252, -8220329429368507605, -8294861676242698827, -8299770080468079954, -8339193796864520803, -8410353044617211568, -8437046006383589784, -8438976104446486307, -8456634614417512433, -8465579815208859871, -8639533785857232862, -8739480561619334892, -8932233076910266584, -9102087309145389149, -9135152589821893130, -9181862820768946749, 1005966352682564970, 1028512276643589790, 104618561781417698, 1064950196043905855, 112985976928537695, 1130557170092703452, 1153087246811817643, 1168263067395645865, 1181253165251712879, 1234450279220588377, 1235528578328242488, 1246095632924785692, 1398972207818014866, 1503387362356614856, 1531163091609683667, 1576639549642827365, 176127536243263200, 1850326271673703056, 1852693779433242222, 2028158485541761723, 2087296166851930177, 2117065546342488501, 2118853807757928087, 2126151187144530538, 214442424887691688, 2229954979637633879, 2246450662945421633, 2598537157451720932, 2697833181014472825, 2771154564041888602, 2782236440012166634, 280848228597580944, 3023089769404515667, 3034328872066363908, 3157881734729908252, 3183081147587380391, 3185266376119526312, 3310718302579204254, 3399512434509026495, 3413063964889961537, 3452984580375732264, 3510307113911564114, 3631581900773472988, 3662440595706866291, 3788129317550054144, 3821468126845792016, 3992422319852338092, 4140027543360385326, 4205725228545201454, 4222206253102852569, 4304803727150805030, 4341687362092853380, 4399615400033738524, 4459343349150993139, 4530423611042649339, 4552508915946832653, 4559631769127444692, 4566818784861568567, 4668181545894058968, 4704450512259603736, 4735036525052432758, 4830730487170059117, 4851861781481410426, 5132811699894794208, 5298746237590038487, 547223580421356605, 5573228672448334845, 563024221547287208, 5820859378637220223, 5922633991422121423, 5973108789268530823, 599068803292954360, 6012776112756389920, 6030791994810955937, 6063409661908440051, 6076393259519474789, 6092481156198013565, 6221636226980376547, 6301336643499188089, 6319195729140676410, 6395301512694036082, 6449482013672981153, 6465574400681688423, 6593314337245504478, 6703626617590080323, 6716716167099001985, 6737061596991258059, 6777730416371068450, 6955703574182215845, 6983613546338207307, 7029431140125626329, 7072046800929505960, 7249448214758104771, 7288898888645823805, 7294259971635646430, 7404694329729734564, 7471681123214330216, 7485724455509988847, 7492431597309764513, 7517907875075727134, 7535620683717279894, 7574264438904804501, 7880937308991458523, 8014193788349246559, 8023892623428676468, 8107901106817729607, 8107980558679933135, 8134751885909642591, 8142146290049995776, 8170571180582534317, 8287028455320079982, 8380824499931187134, 8563416734421856731, 8610424201901637936, 8858138698098199845, 8863818969831369846, 8982782230679876578, 9000073003030305138, 9137256080136088408, 9175001681479269487, 984567617652880615]
INFO  20:14:23 Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to NORMAL
```

Answer (score 1):

To start Cassandra on Windows use Powershell with an elevated admin privilege, not Command Prompt